# Is there a way to easily respond to part(s) of a long email?

Tags: email

This subject may be "almost" off-topic, but I found no other place to ask it...

BACKGROUND:  I'm old-school when it comes to computers.  I come from an age where you were not suppose to requote an entire email.  It was also possible to quote and respond to parts of email with the ">".  Consequently, I really miss the idea of a conversation like email, where I can quote a part of an email, respond to it, quote another part, respond to it, and so on. (I understand that it's now not "proper" (or common) to write long emails.)

I use emails continually, many of which are very long.  I want to respond to only specific things or certain questions.  It seems important, and easier for the reader, if I quote only the specific parts of the email that I am going to give a response to.  I have searched the online email companies (GMail, Yahoo, Outlook) for an option like this, but there appears to be none.  Maybe I have to start importing my emails into an old piece of software to do this, I don't know...  Could someone tell me if there is an easy, effective way to do this?

Comment: IIRC there used to be a way to do inline replies with GMail, but I think that as it got "smarter" the option fell by the wayside.

Answer (score 3):

You can still respond inline if you wish.

In Gmail, click the dots at the bottom and you'll see the email you are responding to. You can go into that email and add extra line breaks and write your responses there if you wish. It'd probably be a good idea to write at the top in the main response that you've edited the earlier email to let readers know where to find your additions.

[image]

You can also do this in every version of Outlook.

[image]